# Magento2: How to remove product images programmatically?

Tags: magento2, product-images

During edit product from front-end I need to remove images of the product 
gallery which are checked by the user to remove it.

Comment: How you can edit product from Front End?

Comment: We are creating a panel on frontend where some user can create/edit/delete the products. But during editing we are facing problem in removing the images of product.

Comment: Please update the question & if possible put the code & error so can help out

Comment: We are not getting any error, we just want to discover that what code we need to implement to remove image of a particular product

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 11):

Below code working fine for me to remove Image Magento 2.

Using Product ID:

```
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productNewId);
$imageProcessor = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor');
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach($images as $child){
    $imageProcessor->removeImage($product, $child->getFile());
}
```

Hope it helps to you

Comment: You shouldn't use ObjectManager... apart from that, your code is good.

Comment: this gives me integrity constraint violations

Comment: Not working for disable images

Comment: Did you fixed integrity constraint violations

Answer (score 8):

We can use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory` to get media gallery. We also need to declare the `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` class which helps us to save the existing product.

We can use Object Manager directly, however, this way isn't good. It's better that we should inject these class in the constructor.

```
/**@var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory **/
protected $product;

/**@var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface **/
protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(
   ......
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
   \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
   ......
)
{
  $this->product = $product;
  $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

In your custom method:

```
//Product id
$productId = 12;
$product = $this->product->create();

$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->load($productId)->getMediaGalleryEntries();

foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
    //We can add your condition here
    unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

#### Should take a look at the Unit test:

--`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Test/Unit/Model/ProductTest.php`
--`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Test/Unit/Model/ProductRepositoryTest.php`
--`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Test/Unit/Model/Product/Gallery/GalleryManagementTest.php`

Comment: using this code when i add other base  image programmatically that image is not set as base image so how to remove all base,thumbnail,small image ?

Comment: @ND17 you want to remove all base, thumbnail, small images? My code above cannot help you anymore?

Comment: your code is remove all images but when i try to save other image as base image, it is not set as base image and if i remove all images and save same image which i am removing than that image is set as base image

Comment: this is happens beacuse cache folder is exist in media\catalog\product

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh i tried above solution but it fires constraint exception?

Comment: @SujeetPandit how about your exception?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh 2 exception(s):

Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mage_data`.`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_VAL_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`value_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity_medi), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` (`value_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `label`, `position`, `disabled`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mage_data`.`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_VAL_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`value_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity_medi)

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, how to delete the duplicate images?

Comment: Hello, someone has success on remove all base,thumbnail,small images?

Answer (score 8):

For me it finally worked based on this article:
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-images-to-product-programmatically-magento-2.html

```
    $gallery = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    if (count($gallery) > 0) {
        foreach($gallery as $image){
            $this->productGallery->deleteGallery($image->getValueId());
        }
        $_product->setMediaGalleryEntries([]);
        $_product->save();
    }
```

Where `productGallery` is an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery`

I hope it helps someone

Comment: Thanks, only your code works after hours of search!! =)

Comment: Yeah saved me a bit of manual labour there!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is all the other code you have to write but when it comes to removing images specifically this solution worked for me. Tested on M2.4.3.

```
private $gallery_rm
    
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery $gallery_rm
) {
    $this->gallery_rm = $gallery_rm;
}

public function removeImagesFromProduct($product_object) {
    // get all images from product object
    $media_gallery_entries = $product_object->getMediaGalleryEntries();

    foreach($media_gallery_entries as $product_img) {
        $this->gallery_rm->deleteGallery($product_img->getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my day. Many thanks. By doing so, you avoided having to save the entire product, which takes a lot of time

Comment: @Bafi you're welcome. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on similar task, I am sharing my code, hope it would help others too.

Fist initialization in constructor

```
protected $productModel;
protected $imageProcessor;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor $imageProcessor,
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->productModel = $productModel;
    $this->imageProcessor = $imageProcessor;
    ...
}
```

Now you can use it in your function

```
$product = $this->productModel->load($productId);
$gallery = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach($gallery as $image){
    $this->imageProcessor->removeImage($product,$image->getFile());
}
$product->save();
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete the specfic images 
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
    set_time_limit(0);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    
    //Instance of object manager
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    //skus
    // $productArray = array("7750087","7750100");
    $file = fopen('deLId.csv', 'r', '"'); // set path to the CSV file
    $header = fgetcsv($file); // get data headers and skip 1st row
    while ( $row = fgetcsv($file, 40000, ",") ) {
        $data_count = count($row);
            if ($data_count < 1) {
                continue;
            }
        $data = array();
        $data = array_combine($header, $row);
        $sku=$data["sku"];
        $productIds=$data["id"];
        $productSkus=explode(',',$productIds);
        // $productSkus=implode(',',$productSkus);
        // print_r(gettype($productSkus));
        // echo gettype($productSkus).PHP_EOL;
        // die();
    
       if (!empty($productSkus)) {
           foreach($productSkus as $key=>$productData){
    
               $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productData);
               $productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
               $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
    
                 foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry){
                    if (!empty($entry)) {   
                        unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
                    }else{
                        echo "already deleted";
                    }
                 }
    
                $product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
                $productRepository->save($product);
    
                echo "Product Image has been deleted for ".$productIds." successfully"." against ".$sku.PHP_EOL;
    
            }
       }
    }
    echo "Yahooooo";
    
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**run below script for remove images from all products**

```
  <?php
    error_reporting(1);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $instance = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
    
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');   
    //$productcollection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'));
    //$productcollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => '1'));
    //$productcollection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('eq' => '4'));
    if(count($productcollection)){
        $i=0;
        foreach($productcollection as $productdata){        
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productdata->getEntityId());
        $productRepo = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
        $exiMediaGallery = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
            
        foreach ($exiMediaGallery as $key => $val) {
            unset($exiMediaGallery [$key]);
        }
            $product->setMediaGalleryEntries($exiMediaGallery);
            $productRepo->save($product);
            echo "\n".$product->getSku()."....".$i;
            $i++;
        }
    }else{
    echo 'No Product Found';
    }
    
    ?>
```