# Programmically deleting product image that exist on multiple stores

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images

I have followed the following post [Magento2: How to remove product images programmatically?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139616/magento2-how-to-remove-product-images-programmatically) which looks like it should work.

However from digging into the Magento 2 code it looks like the image won't delete if it is being used on another store.

So how do I delete an image for all the stores at the same time? For context what I am trying to do is it write a CLI that updates products in for a customers multiple stores.