# magento 2 Remove product specific image programmatically not all the gallery images?

Tags: magento2, gallery-image

I am updating the product from the frontend and I want to only remove specific images which client is deleted not all the images.

Is there any method available ?

help will be appreciated.

Comment: this link will help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139616/magento2-how-to-remove-product-images-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to add/remove image from product in Magento2.

```
    // Instance of object manager
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
*Remove Images From Product*/
$productId = ; // Id of product
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
    unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
$productRepository->save($product);
/*Add Images To The Product*/
$imagePath = "sample.png"; // path of the image
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->save();
```